# Tensorflow GPU error "Your CPU supports instructions... etc."

Tags: python, tensorflow

Just installed Cuda to get Tensorflow using my GPU. I followed the instructions on https://www.tensorflow.org/install/gpu and have run the Cuda tests on https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-installation-guide-microsoft-windows/ (deviceQuery and bandwidthTest) which both were fine.

When I open up PyCharm and run the following code

```
import tensorflow as tf

print(tf.test.is_gpu_available(
    cuda_only=False,
    min_cuda_compute_capability=None
))
```

It evaluates to `True` but I get the following error messages appear:

```
2019-04-12 16:45:48.713478: I tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:141] Your CPU supports instructions that this TensorFlow binary was not compiled to use: AVX2
2019-04-12 16:45:48.918686: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1433] Found device 0 with properties: 
name: GeForce GTX 1070 major: 6 minor: 1 memoryClockRate(GHz): 1.7085
pciBusID: 0000:01:00.0
totalMemory: 8.00GiB freeMemory: 6.64GiB
2019-04-12 16:45:48.919057: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1512] Adding visible gpu devices: 0
True
2019-04-12 16:45:49.497524: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:984] Device interconnect StreamExecutor with strength 1 edge matrix:
2019-04-12 16:45:49.497813: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:990]      0 
2019-04-12 16:45:49.497956: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1003] 0:   N 
2019-04-12 16:45:49.498209: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1115] Created TensorFlow device (/device:GPU:0 with 6389 MB memory) -> physical GPU (device: 0, name: GeForce GTX 1070, pci bus id: 0000:01:00.0, compute capability: 6.1)
```

What do these mean and should I be concerned?

(Running Windows 10, Python 3.6.8, Cuda Toolkit 10.0, Tensorflow 1.13.1)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These are not error messages, but informational messages.  These are indicated by the `I` following date and time.  These occur normally, and are no cause for concern.  The different types of log levels can be found [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/logging).

Comment: Ahhh - reading them, they didn't seem problematic but I'm something of a beginner and I'm used to anything appearing in red being something that need's addressing.
Thanks!!

Comment: No problem.  If this answer works for you, please click the check mark next to it so people can find it in the future.